# When do you declare a WebDriver driver public or private when using @BeforeMethod and @BeforeClass annotations

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testng

In different testNG scripts, I have seen 'WebDriver driver' being declared public or private and both have worked. I have read about nested classes and all that but it is unclear when to use the two options particularly when either will work. The selenium IDE script I have just converted to TestNG/Webdriver declared has private 'WebDriver driver'. For the same test case, I used public in my own script and that also worked. Can some explain with an example when to use what or is okay to use either?

Answer (score 1):

The "access level" of a declared variable or method refers to the ability to access that component from other classes outside of the current class.  Declaring something "public" means that the component is fully accessible from any other class.  Declaring it "private" means it is only accessible from within the current class.  There is also "protected", which means it can be access from subclasses, and "blank", which is also called "package private", which means it can be accessed from any class in the same declared package.

These distinctions can be pretty important in the code that gets deployed to your production container, to do the work that the application is intended for.

However, they are less important in test classes, that are only executed on the desktop or on a CI server, and which don't get deployed to the "business server".

Nevertheless, it's a good habit to declare "instance variables" as private, simply because that's what you should be doing in production code.  In reality, in test classes, it generally won't make any difference what access level you give them.

Comment: So, this means that if I only have one class in my project with one or more methods, it's not important if 'WebDriver driver' is public or private. Correct? Access level becomes important when there is  more than one class,  right? Is there any effect of the access level on methods?

Comment: Yes, technically it would be easier to specify no access level at all (package private), but it's also a good habit to always declare them private. However, if all you ever write are test classes, then perhaps it doesn't matter. Access levels impact methods identically.